# Schema in production is different that in development

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel, planetscale

I'm having some trouble using prisma and planetscale

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Flor Esmaltada",
    "price": 75,
    "image": "https://ik.imagekit.io/gabriellazcano/imajo/Flor_2/flor_2_blanca_transparente_5RPp4nKfA.png",
    "description": "Flor de plata 925 con piedra austriaca en muchisimos colores, elige los que más te gusten. Hechos a mano en México.",
    "categories": [
        "piedras"
    ],
    "alternativeImages": [
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/gabriellazcano/imajo/flor_con_tallo/flor_con_tallo_lado_Hx8HBrH7e.png",
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/gabriellazcano/imajo/flor_con_tallo/flor_con_tallo_lateral_CP5MsqTGQ.png"
    ],
    "colors": []
}
```

Im getting this object in dev

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Flor Esmaltada",
    "price": 75
}
```

And this one in production

In planescale shell I'm getting the first schema and all the objects are there but when deployed to Vercel it only shows those 3 fields

I'm expecting having the first schema on production

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Vercel, is the environment variable for your database the correct one? It might be for the wrong branch.

Comment: Did you follow this guide of Automatic Prisma Migrations with PlanetScale?
https://planetscale.com/docs/tutorials/automatic-prisma-migrations
It seems some of the latest migrations would not have applied on your database.